# R, rowMeans by Column in data.frame

Tags: r

I have a csv that I've read in and is now a data.frame within R.  My file name is MyRData007.  My header information goes until row 5 (main column headers are on row 4).  My ID is in column A.  I simply need to create two separate rowMeans for each ID.  The data is in rows 5-147.  For the first mean it's columns 4-15; the second mean it's for columns 6-21.  Ultimately I'll should have a new variable with a mean for each of the 143 rows.  This is what I tried:

```
> mRNA<-rowMeans(MyRData007)[5:147,(4:15)]
> Protein<-rowMeans(MyRData007)[5:147,(16:21)]
```

But I get an error?

```
Error in rowMeans(MyRData007) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Brackets before end-parentheses:  `rowMeans(MyRData007[5:147,(4:15)])`

Comment: Please include an example of your data. The best way to do this is to enter `dput(MyRData007[1:20,])` in the console, and copy and past the output into your question.

Comment: Wow - I just did that and its much longer than what I "see" in the csv file!  Should I still paste it in?

Comment: Thanks to all, this was a big help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text='this is a header
                 this is another header
                 this too is one
                 and this is also
                 id code status value
                 1 2 3 4
                 2 32 43 23
                 3 3 43 32
                 4 232 323 55')
df
    V1   V2      V3     V4
1 this   is       a header
2 this   is another header
3 this  too      is    one
4  and this      is   also
5   id code  status  value
6    1    2       3      4
7    2   32      43     23
8    3    3      43     32
9    4  232     323     55
```

So when you try to call `rowMeans` you get an error:

```
rowMeans(df)
Error in rowMeans(df) : 'x' must be numeric
```

You get this error because you are trying to get the mean of non-numeric values, which makes no sense. Your attempts to subset the data didn't work because you put the brackets outside the call to `rowMeans`, which tells it to subset the output of `rowMeans`, not the data going in.

The fundamental problem is that you can't have headers information in a R `data.frame`. All data in a column of a data frame must be the same type, so if you have characters in some rows, you cant have numbers in others.

**How can you fix this?**

Read in your data with `read.table` using the `skip = 4` argument. This will make it skip over the header information rows to generate a data frame with only your data. If your file is a `.csv` you'll also need to specify `sep=','` and `header=T`:

```
df2 <- read.table(text='this is a header
                 this is another header
                 this too is one
                 and this is also
                 id code status value
                 1 2 3 4
                 2 32 43 23
                 3 3 43 32
                 4 232 323 55', skip = 4, header = T)
rowMeans(df2)
[1]   2.50  25.00  20.25 153.50
```

`read.csv` is just a wrapper for `read.table` and using it is the same as using `read.table` with the following options:

```
read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE)
```

Generally, it's better to use `read.table` since it gives you more control. The most important example being to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to prevent strings from being converted to `factors` (an extremely annoying default).

Comment: Thank you - I used read.csv instead - is that going to cause a problem?  Thanks again for your great reply!

Comment: `read.csv` is just a wrapper for `read.table`. should be fine.

Comment: Thanks to all!  Something is going on with my data, for example, for the last row (which has values) I'm getting NA?  And the means for some rows look way off?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing your data. If you're using RStudio, you can type `View(MyRData007)` to see your data frame in spreadsheet view. You can do a sanity check to make sure the data is being parsed correctly. If it's not, but you can't figure out how to make it work, ask a new question about it!

Comment: As for your last row, are you sure it's the actual last row and not an extra row tacked on to the end during importing?

Comment: Thanks divibisan - you helped me big-time.  I had the header statement incorrect during my import (should have been F instead of T).  I'm very grateful for your help!